# running several nodes in different machines using bash or python script

Tags: ros, bashrc, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use multiple machines to run several nodes. The idea is to use ssh from several terminals. I am workingon running these nodes using a python scipt using sshpass command. I am aware of the security issues but all machines are mine.
before i run the command in a python script or in a pash file I run it in the command line and it didnt work:

I wrote the folllwoing in the command line:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@host rosrun package_name node_name
```

but it didnt work... The error was :

```
bash: rosrun: command not found
```

What should I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202830/running-several-nodes-in-different-machines-using-bash-or-python-script/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stuff like this is usually solved with the [machine](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine) tag in a launch file.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6